# iOS autolayout detail page - resize labels by number of lines and so

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am new to iOS and AutoLayout and I need a little help. I have this detail page:
[image: Detail page from app]

My problems can be split to 2 things:

- I need to set labels to change height by number of lines in text. So for example that first label after image that has 5 lines and after that starts label "Akce" and so. I need to have this with every label.
- I want to change height of image too but keep aspect ratio. So every image would resize to fill width (every time it would be something like 300px) and then from width there would be calculated height to keep aspect ratio. Then labels would start after image ends.

If it helps here is screenshot of my controller (I've tried add some constraints but without luck for now). Maybe I should mention that everything is in scrollViewer:
[image: Controls in detailcontroller]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your constraints are setup correctly, to resize the labels you need to set the following properties:

```
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:YOURMAXWIDTH]; //this would be the max width you want your label to be...
```

For the image, you should just be able to do:

```
[IMAGEVIEW setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]; //Possibly be UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```